# Isekai manga where people draw magic from fairies

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember it was about a girl who back in her world could summon spirits and make contracts with them. Then, in the world she went to, there are only fairies that people draw their magic from. And she managed to summon a spirit of a lake near the mansion she resides in. Supposedly, spirits are way stronger then fairies. And she’s the only one with one. The spirit is in the shape of a knight.

Comment: "Isekai manga where people draw magic from fairies" is a far better title (more descriptive and informative) than "I need help finding the name of an isekai manga" (which applies to every story-id question about isekai manga).  Also, adding "Please help me find the name. I can’t seem to remember." is unnecessary, as we already know that you want us to find the name and that you can't remember; saying it again won't help you.  Please stop rolling the post back.

Comment: I agree with jwodder. You're trying to roll it back to a *less good* version of the question, one that's less likely to get you the answer you seek.